# Detect Users Login through Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to find a way to detect User Log Ins on my site through Google Analytics.

Basically, Unique visits to my site with the name of the User.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible, simply use _gaq.push(): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push

Also: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#sessionLevel